# Express - Cannot POST /quotes

Tags: node.js, express, post

Note I did shuffle through a LOT of answers, couldn't find one that matched mine.

Trying to learn express and node. When submitting the form in index.html, the following returns "Cannot POST /quotes" in browser and nothing in the console, but the GET method works fine and loads the page.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("listening to port 3000");
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Hellloooooooooo!");
});
```

index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/quotes" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="quote" name="quote">
        <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: app.post('/post', (req, res) => { should change to /quotes

Comment: You don't have a route defined in express for `/quotes`, only `/post`. Your client is trying to make a post to `/quotes` as defined by the `action` attribute of your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no quotes route, you have only 2 routes and only one post `/post` route but no post `/quotes` route

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("listening to port 3000");
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Hellloooooooooo!");
});

// just make a simple quotes route

app.post('/quotes', (req, res) => {
    console.log("hello from quotes route!");
});
```

Comment: That does it! Thanks!

Comment: Was waiting for the time limit ^.^